# What's the fastest way to farm gold?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I'm out of gold. I spent it all on tickets and Mii outfits in the shop.  At the rate of normal matches I'm seeing about 180-220 GP per match.   This is pretty slow, especially with some pricey items like:

- 3 star support spirits: 6k GP
- Tickets for Classic Mode: 5k GP
- Mii Outfits: 300-1500 GP
- etc.

[image]

Is there a faster, or more efficient way to farm gold? At my current balance I'm set to run out within the next few shop rotations, so I'd hopefully like to have enough to buy both outfits, soundtracks, and anything else bonus in the shop.

Comment: It'd also be interesting to know if there's a good strategy for the green coin things as well, since buying spirits or anything from the shops in WoL cost a decent amount and they don't add up very fast.

Comment: @question marks Expeditions and dismantling non-used souls are your best bet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YZDUCIKW2o).

In text form,

- Make a new ruleset that's based on stocks
- Set stocks to 1
- Set time limit to 1 minute
- Set CPU level to 1
- Turn off stage hazards
- Turn off items
- Set launch rate (under advanced options) to 0.5%
- Save ruleset
- Choose any character, leave CPU at random
- Choose any stage
- Move to the middle of the stage and repeatedly duck (Coin rewards appear to be partly based on how many inputs are fired)
- The CPU will likely be unable to kill you
- After 1 minute, kill the CPU in sudden death (or be killed, it doesn't matter)

This should net you 300-500 coins. Commenters say they reach 1k with 2 players ducking, but I can't replicate this.

Addendum: To save more time, set stage selection to random and turn off all but one stage from the list of available stages that appear when selecting random.

Comment: Pro-tip: Pick Marth and Lucina. They have (apparently) slightly faster duck animations, making them better for this method of gold farming if you do it long enough. Also, control both players by putting a JoyCon in each hand and just flick the analog-stick to duck.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get 55k gold after a party with a bunch of people playing Smash all night, but that dried out pretty quick...
The 1-minute test game as mentioned above just netted me 338g on first game, then I did two player, and netted 459g with same ruleset.

It's very grindy, but without a party lasting hours, it may work. I forget how much you can get with online games... but at that rate of 1.5 mins per game (counting load times) and 300g per game, that's 200g/min, 12,000 per hour, which means 1h15m of total grinding per legendary bought minion.

It appears that Spirits points shop sells different spirits than the gold shop, so I guess we'll need a ton of gold to get all the spirits!

Answer (score 1):

Jeremiah is right but you can increase the gold even further by picking Ice Climbers and if you have to controllers do 2 player ice climbers gets you 500 to 600 each game

Comment: Welcome to the site Velux! This information you've posted is really helpful, but answers should able to stand on their own. So I'd suggest you include some additional details in your answer to make it more complete, even if that means it overlaps with Jeremiahs answer (you can do this using the edit on your post).

Answer (score 0):

I just did a Century Smash with my brother. It took us 2 minutes and 45 seconds to finish and netted like 530 gold. I've only done one of these but it was very easy with two players and seemed like a good gold for time spent ratio while not getting boring like spamming duck for a solid minute.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a long way, but it’s kinda worth it.

Stock = up to 99 (the higher the better)
CPU’s = 8 (I’d recommend lv 6)
Any map (or two if you want to spice it up)
No time limit

It’s long, but for 20 stocks I got 974 gold in one battle.

Comment: Unless that took you less than 5 minutes then it's really not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some "Rematch" items, I think you can get away with fighting a "Legend" (4-star) spirit character on the spirit board during an "Event", and get some good coins. I got ~1500 from Pauline for example, during the "Sleve-Free Zone" event right now. Then use "Rematch" item, and rinse and repeat. More fun than the other grinding perhaps. (Admittedly, the Pauline battle is fairly challenging though)